# surcharging a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to know how I can surcharge a third party plugin. For example, I would like to load the select2() plugin, only for non touch browsers.

```
(function( $ ){

    $.fn.mySelect2 = function(options) {
        var $container = $(this);
        var DEFAULTS = {};
        var options = $.extend(DEFAULTS, options);

        return this.each(function(){
            // only loads the select2 plugin on non touch browsers
            if(typeof(window.ontouchstart) != 'undefined') {
                $('.select2').select2(options);
            }
        });
    }
})( jQuery );
```

would like to be able to write the following :

```
$('.select2').mySelect2()                    // inits the plugin
$('.select2').mySelect2('destroy')           // destroys the plugin
$('.select2').mySelect2({width: '220px'});   // inits the plugin with a rewritted option
```

The previous lines works for init and editing options but not for the methods ('destroy', 'readonly', ...).

The fact is I would like to do the same for several others plugins/librairies and I cannot know each methods or properties of the third parties plugin.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is that when you use `$.extend(DEFAULTS, options)` while options is a string, you actually convert this string into an object (array of characters for the given string).

So you should check the type of options variable and extend it with defaults only if it is not string.

Also, to be able to use this plugin not only for `'.select2'`, you probably should replace it by `$(this)`

```
$.fn.mySelect2 = function(options) {
    var $container = $(this);
    var DEFAULTS = {};
    if (typeof options != "string")
     options = $.extend(DEFAULTS, options);

    return this.each(function(){
        // only loads the select2 plugin on non touch browsers
        if(typeof(window.ontouchstart) != 'undefined') {
            $(this).select2(options);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, as you said, the problem came from $.extend().